# Why multiple stores are getting created on iCloud while syncing Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud, icloud-documents

I am working on iCloud Documents syncing and have a toggle between storing locally and on the cloud.

I used this to set this up: http://iaintheindie.com/2014/07/07/icloud-core-data-part-3-complete-stack/

The issue is at some point, there is another store that is created and it becomes the store from which data is pulled. This results in a "loss" of data because it isn't the store where objects were stored/changed. In this case there are 3 stores that are created. Each with a new file path.

[Picture of Multiple iCloud stores in file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhd4d.png)